# Sorting pandas series sub values

Tags: pandas, sorting, series

So in doing some research, I am seeing a function which will sort the values of a pandas series. Referring to the link https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html and I get the concept from the example below given below:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, 3, 10, 5])
>>> s
0     NaN
1     1.0
2     3.0
3     10.0
4     5.0
dtype: float64

s.sort_values(ascending=True)
1     1.0
2     3.0
4     5.0
3    10.0
0     NaN
dtype: float64
```

However, in my series, the data that I am trying to sort is the actually in the form of an example below:

```
0     22 11 03 04 06 05
1     03 12 01 22 07 31
2     01 10 02 13 15 61
3     ...
4     ...
dtype: float64
```

My desired output that I am trying to achieve is:

```
0     03 04 05 06 11 22
1     01 03 07 12 22 31
2     01 02 10 13 15 61
3     ...
4     ...
dtype: float64
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your input is ambiguous, assuming `s` your Series, what is the output of `s.head().tolist()`? There is no way that `22 11 03 04 06 05` (whatever this object is) can give a `float64` dtype.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pd.Series.apply` to iterate through each element of the pandas `Series`, then split the values at each space (generating a list of numbers, stored as strings) and apply Python `sorted` function. Finally, you can join the sorted list back into a single string.

Here's an example on how to do it:

```py
# Import the pandas library
import pandas as pd

# == Create Dummy Data =========================================================
data = {
    '0': '22 11 03 04 06 05',
    '1': '03 12 01 22 07 31',
    '2': '01 10 02 13 15 61',
}

# Create a pandas Series object named 's' from the 'data' dictionary.
# The keys will act as indexes for the Series and the values will be the data.
s = pd.Series(data)

# == Solution to Question ======================================================
# Apply a lambda function to each value in the Series 's'.
# The lambda function first splits the string at each space, creating a list of
# numbers (as strings). Then it sorts this list of strings, and finally joins
# the sorted list back into a single string.
# The result is a new Series with the same indexes but sorted number strings as values.
s.apply(lambda value: ' '.join(sorted(value.split())))
# Returns:
#
# 0    03 04 05 06 11 22
# 1    01 03 07 12 22 31
# 2    01 02 10 13 15 61
# dtype: object
```